# Debugging memory leak in Ruby on Rails background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory-leaks

I've noticed that my Ruby on Rails app seems to have a memory leak which creeps up to Heroku's 512mb limit over a 12 – 24 hour period:

[image]

I've used Siege to hit the Puma server with a lot of requests and haven't noticed that affecting memory. The app itself is pretty basic, so I am pretty sure the problem lies with the background workers instead.

Here's my clock.rb file which schedules the background workers:

```
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork
  configure do |config|
    config[:tz] = 'UTC'
    config[:max_threads] = 128
    config[:thread] = true
  end
  every(10.minutes, 'Start studies') { StartStudiesWorker.perform_async }
  every(10.minutes, 'Finish studies') { FinishStudiesWorker.perform_async }
  every(5.minutes, 'Send questions') { EnqueueQuestionsWorker.perform_async }
  every(5.minutes, 'Check sent sms status') { CheckSmsStatusWorker.perform_async }
  every(1.day, 'Send random questions', at: '00:15') { EnqueueRandomQuestionsWorker.perform_async }
end
```

And the Puma configuration file, with comments removed:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
preload_app!
plugin :tmp_restart
```

I've done a bit of research already and noticed that most articles & questions are about debugging memory leaks in the main app, not necessarily background workers. So I guess my questions are:

- Do my configuration files for Clock and Puma look okay?
- What's the best place to start debugging the background workers?